# Does Firebase do Geospatial?

Tags: firebase

I would like to retrofit Firebase to an existing app.  The existing app uses CouchDB and GeoCouch to ensure that the client only retrieves data that is 'near' the user.

Does/will Firebase support this type of feature or is this something I will need to do myself?

Comment: You mean geospatial _indexing_?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We don't directly support geospatial queries. Currently, you'll need to add this functionality to your app on your own. Other users storing geodata in Firebase have had a lot of luck denormalizing data and using geohashes as keys. Geohashes let you "search" for nearby regions by truncating the key. Take a look at the description here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash

Answer (score 15):

For those still coming here through Google Search, Firebase supports this now. Check this blogpost for more details https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-06-23-geofire-two-point-oh.html

Comment: seems it is supporting the on-event search queries but not the on-demand search queries.